# Programmatically set Proxy URL for WIFI

Tags: ios, proxy, swift3

Is it possible to programmatically change the proxy settings for a specific wifi connection in swift, either globally or locally for an app?

There are sources that say this was possible some time ago (2008) but cannot seem to find anything that shows it is currently possible (iOS 8+). Would I still need to use a .pac or .mobileconfig file? Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: I'm looking to do this same thing. Doesn't appear to be a lot of docs in the subject.